# Fuzzy match on google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to fuzzy match two columns in google sheets, i've tried numerous formulas but I think it's going to come down to a script to help out.

I have a column with product ID's e.g.

- E20067

and then I have another sheet with another column which has image url's relating to this product code such as

- http://wholesale.test.com/product/E20067/web_images/E20067.jpg
- http://wholesale.test.com/product/E20067/high_res/E20067.jpg
- http://wholesale.test.com/product/E20067/high_res/E20067-2.jpg

What I'm wanting to do is "fuzzy" match both of these columns for their product ID, and then create a new column for each match. So it would have the product ID then on the same row in multiple columns each product image URL - like the image below:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in google sheets using a script or a formula?

Answer (score 2):

In Google sheets there are a few powerful 'regex' formulas.

Suppose, you have ID list in column A, and URL list in column B

[image]

Then use formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,JOIN("|",$A$1:$A$3))
```

It will match one of ID's. Drag the formula down to see the result as in picture above.

See more [info here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but if each product ID has multiple images e.g. 5x images?

Comment: This works great to get a static column between data sets - but it's stopping due to it being over 50,000 characters?

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but, in case you find yourself here, search for my Google Sheets add-on called [Flookup](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/flookup/593806014962). It should do exactly what you want.

For this case, you can use this function:

```
FLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, lookup_col, index_num, threshold, [rank])
```

The parameter details are:

1. `lookup_value`: the value you're looking up
2. `table_array`: the table you want to search
3. `lookup_col`: the column you want to search
4. `index_num`: the column you want data to be returned from
5. `threshold`: the percentage similarity below which data should not be returned
6. `rank`: the nth best match (i.e. if the first one isn't to your liking)

- You can find out more at the [official website](https://www.getflookup.com) (examples and such).

Please note that, whereas the OP appears to want the whole list of possible matches, Flookup will only return one result at a time.

Comment: Flookup library works great for me. Also includes formulas to get multiple results. Find it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flookup/ejcjhjbhdleeagbfpnkhaljhnoollhig

Comment: Thanks for the support @mozboz and thank you for adding the link to Flookup. 
I will update my post to include the link to the website as well

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. I am assuming the product codes are in Sheet1 and the URLs are in Sheet2. Both in column A:

```
=iferror(transpose(FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$A,Search("*"& A2 &"*",Sheet2!$A$2:$A))))
```

Copy down.

If you want to show the image instead of the url try:

```
=arrayformula(image(iferror(transpose(FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$A,Search("*"& A2 &"*",Sheet2!$A$2:$A))))))
```